# Google Cloud Scheduler trigger dataflow template batch job fails with "INVALID ARGUMENT"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a dataflow template that I schedule or trigger using a Google Cloud Scheduler. We change the job quite often during development that involves changes to the arguments as well. Quite often we find that trigger fails with status 400 and `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. Since there are multiple arguments it becomes difficult to figure which argument that is passed is invalid.

Is there a better way to figure out which argument is causing the trigger to fail rather than manual?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Common error guidance: Bad error](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#bad-request-shuffler-logs) you can not see in Stackdirver those arguments.

If it written in Python you can expose the arguments using [logging](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#worker_log_message_code_example):

```py
# import Python logging module.
import logging

class ExtractWordsFn(beam.DoFn):

  def process(self, *arg, **kwarg):
    logging.info('Arguments: %s', arg)
    logging.info('Key-value args: %s', kwarg)
    my,arguments = arg
    # REST OF YOUR CODE
```